Is the image of a $G_\delta$ set under a continuous injection again a $G_\delta$?
Question: Is the image of a $G_\delta$ set in $X$ under some continuous injection $f:X\to Y$ again a $G_\delta$ set in $Y$?
I want to know this mainly for the case where $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\Bbb R$. But, I also want to know if this is true in general?
A $G_\delta$ set is a set which can be expressed as a countable intersection of open sets.
My attempt: I think yes. I know a $G_\delta$ set is a set which can be expressed as a countable intersection of open sets. For proving the given statement, let $S$ be any $G_\delta$ subset of $[0,1]$. Then we need to prove that $f(S)$ is also a $G_\delta$ set. That is, we need to show that $f(S)$ can be expressed as a countable intersection of open sets. I am unable to proceed further from this.

What do you mean with the continuous injection? Are you asking whether if $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ (like $X=[0,1]$ in $Y=\Bbb R$), then  any $G_\delta$ subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$ in $Y$? Or are you considering any continuous injection $f:X\to Y$? And are you assuming $Y=\Bbb R$? and moreover $X=[0,1]$? And what made you hope the answer could be Yes? Did you try to find a counterexample? Can you provide some more substantial "attempt"?

@AnneBauval  By Continuous injection, I mean, a function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which continuous and injective as well. Yes, I want to know this, when $X=[0, 1]$ & $Y=\mathbb{R}$. But, I also want to know, is this true in general?

@AnneBauval , I added My attempt with details about, what I know. But after editing, my added details are removed

Please add them again (this probably happened because I was editing simultaneously). By the way, I included in the post your previous comment, so you can delete it.

@AnneBauval So why you edited it? In another comment you are saying that, question doesn't seems to meet standards on this site!

@AnneBauval No! This is not my post! You had edited it and on other hand you are saying that, question doesn't seems to meet standards on this site! I have written, my attempt in details! You hide that details!

Sorry but I could not see these details (though I truly want to!). I am not responsible for the behaviour of this site in case of conflicting edits.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

@AnneBauval thanks, I will read it, next time I will try to ask well received question. One suggestion, please don't remove any effort/attempt added by questioner while editing.

I won't roll back your last edit but I find it a noisance: again, there is no "attempt" in it. Only repetition and padding, so (again) this question still doesn't meet the standards for this site because it shows absolutely no effort to either prove or disprove the conjecture.

I personally submit that we should not hold this question and its apparently noisy edit history to the usual standards, especially as it appears OP is genuinely engaged in it and not just looking for a freebie. I'm not looking to establish precedent, but something weird evidently happened to (at least) one of the edits.

Question is closed! I saw this written on above post "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc". I had provided these two, but someone edited it & hide them! & even Voted for close! Thank to David gao sir who edited it again and added the hidden part. But still question is closed!

I know it's frustrating, but being closed (although I would not have closed this question) is not really necessarily a bad state, especially as you already have an answer you accepted. I'm inclined to vote to re-open, but (a) I think five votes are needed to actually re-open the question, which perhaps not enough people will provide; and (b) some readers may be put off by your repeatedly insisting that your edits were hidden somehow. I see that, but returning to that point too often may not appear to your benefit.

This is true if the domain is $[0, 1]$ (or more generally any compact space). Indeed, let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous injection and $X$ be compact. Let $S \subset X$ be $G_\delta$. Then $X \setminus S$ is $F_\sigma$, i.e., $X \setminus S = \cup_{n = 1}^\infty K_n$ for some closed $K_n \subset X$. Since $X$ is compact, $K_n$ is compact for all $n$.
Now, as $f$ is injective, we have $f(S) = f(X) \setminus (\cup_{n = 1}^\infty f(K_n))$. Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, we have $f(X)$ is compact. In $\mathbb{R}$ (or more generally any metric space), any compact subspace is automatically closed and any closed subspace is automatically $G_\delta$, whence $f(X)$ is $G_\delta$. Furthermore, $K_n$ is compact, so $f(K_n)$ is compact and thus closed, hence,
$$f(S) = f(X) \cap (\cap_{n = 1}^\infty (\mathbb{R} \setminus f(K_n)))$$
is a $G_\delta$ set.
The above shows the claim is true if the domain is compact (in particular $[0, 1]$) and the codomain is a metric space (in particular $\mathbb{R}$). Let me also observe here that the claim is not true without these assumptions. For example, if one fixes an enumeration of the rationals $\{q_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$, then $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(n) = q_n$ is a continuous injection. $\mathbb{N}$ is a $G_\delta$ set in itself, but $f(\mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Very interesting answer! However, this question doesn’t seem to meet the standards for the site. Answering it encourages low-quality questions. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@AnneBauval The question is perfectly clear to me. And the OP did attempt the question. You removed that attempt in your edits. Admittedly the attempt is lacking, and I don’t necessarily disagree that perhaps it is more just stating definitions than actual attempts. But it is an attempt that provided the requisite context that made the question perfectly reasonable to answer for me. If you disagree, vote to close the question or whatever. Unless it’s closed, I’m fully within my rights to answer here, preferably without you claiming everything doesn’t meet the standards everywhere.

(And just to clarify, I’m not referring to any later possible edits by OP to add more details. I’m simply referring to the earliest version of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4936757/1)

@David Gao Sir, I understand your answer upto the first para. But after that, I didn't get it. "As f is injective we have,....... How we get that from injectivity?

@GeneralMathematics Any injective map is a bijection onto its range, so $f(S) = f(X \setminus (\cup_{n = 1}^\infty K_n)) = f(X) \setminus f(\cup_{n = 1}^\infty K_n) = f(X) \setminus \cup_{n = 1}^\infty f(K_n)$.

The question is also "perfectly clear to me", but the alledged "attempt" was empty: just a wordy rephrasing of the conjecture. Whence my removing it, to make the post more readable) + my questions in comments (what made you hope the answer could be Yes? Did you try to find a counterexample? Can you provide some more substantial "attempt"?) + my vote to close for lack of any substantial effort (but I will of course retract if the post is improved!)

@AnneBauval yes I know I just write the defi. But, I had written What I know. Also I had added that, to prove the given we need to show, $f(S)$ is countable intersection of open sets! But by removing my attempt, now question/post look like someone Just type the question and posted it directly without any details. In fact someone may thought even I know definitions of $G_\delta$ or not! Its Ok You had edited it! But on other hand, you are commenting that, Question doesn't meets standards for this site! Really? It's genuine question on mathematics! It's not like that, if 1=5 then 12=?

@DavidGao sir, thank you so much for this wonderful answer! I learned lot from it than any text on such topics. Further, I like to know, $f(K_n)$ is compact and hence closed. So it is $G_\delta$ set for every $n$ Am I correct?

@GeneralMathematics Yes. $f(K_n)$ is closed and any closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is $G_\delta$. I never used that in the proof, but that is correct.

@GeneralMathematics This was indeed a "genuine question on mathematics", but it still doesn't meet the standards for this site because (again) it shows absolutely no effort to either prove or disprove the conjecture (only trivial and lenghty rephrasing, therefore removed).

@AnneBauval what's main purpose of this site? To help students in mathematics! (Or something else?) As you can see! I read the whole answer and not only that, I have asked  questions for steps too. So isn't this is learning mathematics? Lastly, I want to say, sometimes we don't know how to proceed! This happenes with every beginner! So what you want? We beginners, never asked questions! if we don't know how to proceed? Or we beginners should write anything "that makes no sense" in place of effort! & post the question?

& yes, the negative votes is due to that bad editing which hides the attempt part! I can't see option to reverse that editing!
